# JavaScript file generated by typeScript does not contain comments and have formatting issue

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, typescript, web-essentials

I am using following :

- TypeScript version : 0.9.5
- WebEssential version : 3.7
- Visual Studio : 2012

**After saving the TypeScript file, the JS file does not contains the commented code.**

I am also facing some extra space issue in the JS file. After every '**if**' and '**for**' statement, now there is extra white-space between the 'if' and the '('. Earlier the code was generated as **'if('** now the code is generated as **'if ('**, becuase of thsi extra space, repository treat there is a difference in previous version of JavaScript file and the current version.

**Earlier WebEssentials gave option to retain comments which is missing now - See the image below - These options are not available with WebEssentials now.**

[image: Earlier WebEssentials gave option to retain comments which is missing now]

See the below image to understand spacing issue 
[image]

Where can I find setting to avoid extra space and force JS file to retain the comments added in TS file?

I looked at the **Tools > Options > Web Essentials > TypeScript** setting and **Tools > Options > Text Editor > TypeScript** in visual studio but could not find anything that would help me.

[I just read the extra spacing issue will be addressed in v1.0 of TypeScript](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/561)

Answer (score 0):

> Earlier WebEssentials gave option to retain comments which is missing now

This option has been moved into Project Properties in Visual Studio 2013 + TypeScript 0.9.5 onwards : 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/12/05/announcing-typescript-0-9-5.aspx

If you are on an older version of visual studio you can bypass the visual studio build pipeline and maintain it externally using something like grunt-ts : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#compiler-support